# SQL Database structure/model for a weather station

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need suggestions how desig an sql database to stay scalable. 
I have multiple weather stations and each generate new data (Temperature, Humidity, Rain, Pressure ... ) in every 15 minutes. The problem is that every Station has different set of sensors so if I put all data in the same Table I will have lot of unused Fields.
Whats the best solution.

Comment: Create several tables and use JOIN

Comment: If it's normalised, you won't have any unused fields

Comment: Everything's DECIMAL, right?

Comment: Yes, everything is in Decimal format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stations have different sensors i.e it would be better to break down the stations into logical chunks wherein few stations will have specific columns.

For example:

Considering this as your schema: 
 (StationId,StationName,Temperature, Humidity, Rain, Pressure)

You could breakdown into:

- (StationId,Temperature)
- (StationId,Humidity)
- (StationId,Pressure)
- (StationId,Rain)
- (StationId,StationName)

Since it's a streaming application, we would want to save storage as having NULL fields will quickly lead to huge redundant data.

Relational Database Systems are not the perfect choice for streaming applications because of such issues.

Columnar databases are specially designed for a handing data at scale and are a excellent candidate for streaming applications.